# how to set an appropriate version for a lib when i'm building it from sources

Tags: build-process, packaging, autotools

As an example of my problem let's use libqb (https://github.com/ClusterLabs/libqb).

To install it from the sources I do the next:

```
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

The problem is that the version in "/usr/lib/pkgconfig/libqb.pc" is UNDEFINED.
I suspect that I have to pass a parameter to ./configure but I don't know which one.
I do it on Debian.

Comment: This looks more like a bug in the libpq software. Try contacting the author.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways to get sources:

1. use git ($ git clone)
2. download sources in an archive

In case of using git, you won't see this problem, because it uses git to get correct version of sources during build.

In case of archive you have to create `.tarball-version` file in the top dir and put there version you want. For example: `$ echo "0.17.0" > .tarball-version`.

P.S.: there will be created `.version` file during build. So, if you did any changes to `.tarball-version` then you have to remove `.version` file.